# Can I do Q-in-Q vlans between Dell and Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, vlan, networking, dell, powerconnect

Our Head Office is connected to our DR location between an L2 tunnel provided by our ISP.

I need to establish a Q-in-Q setup between both sides to pass multiple VLANs through. Our head office has a Cisco switch, and our DR has a dell switch. Is it possible to setup Q-in-Q between those two pieces of hardware? Or does the hardware need to be the same on both ends?

Comment: The more important question is does your provider support Q in Q?

Comment: Yes they support Q-in-Q. They are the ones who recommended it

Comment: As long as both devices support it (Cisco does, not sure about Dell), you should be OK